# Cortana and Spotlight not working properly after reset

Tags: windows-10, cortana, windows-spotlight

Hello wonderful SU community. This is my first question here.
I'm experiencing a very unsettling problem and I hope you find an answer - because I've been trying for an entire month without success.

After an unknown issue while boggling with my Windows PC's camera certificates, everything went BSOD and I had to reset my computer. I chose the option "keep my files". I sat, and overlooked my PC until it came back to life.

The first thing I noticed was Cortana not working properly. The main issue is **Cortana won't find any freshly installed application**, not even after a reboot, or after playing around with Indexing Options. It *does, however, find new documents.* Indexing Options work fine, as long as it's for folders and documents.

I've looked for solutions: **creating a new user, deleting old Cortana, then downloading and installing a new Cortana with PowerShell will work, but applications and programs installed after this procedure won't show up.**
Also, any new user seem to have a similar problem.

On top of this, Windows Spotlight stopped working either. I'm constantly getting the same image (I believe that's the "default one") and there are no widgets, no "Like what you see?" buttons or anything else. This seems to happen with every user, newly created or not.

*What I've already tried:*

- PowerShell, many many **many** flavors and versions of that solution.
- SFC /scannow (doesn't find anything).
- Creating a new user and deleting old Cortana folder. As I said, it fixes the problem only temporarily.
- Rebooting, whenever was necessary.

I have moved all my files from the first ever user I created on this computer to a new one; made sure AppData was not transferred. No luck. This problem is seriously bugging me and I hope there is some way to fix it. I'm seriously starting to think this is affecting other parts of Windows I haven't noticed yet; and it has something to do with the way I had to reset it.

Comment: I have performed a clean install of Windows 10.  Everything seems to be okay now.  Thanks.